# In Windows Server 2008, Why does my BIOS and Computer Properties Show All My Installed RAM, but Task Manager Does Not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, bios

I am running Windows Server 2008 on a Dell Inspiron 530 as a poor Dev Shop's development server.  We are using Hyper-V, and need lots of RAM.

We currently have 6Gb of RAM installed, but when booted into 64-bit Win2k8 Std Ed. - the Task Manager reports only 3Gb+ - and I cannot run my 2 VMs, configured for 2Gb each.

The BOIS setup screen shows the 6Gb installed, and the Computer Properties in Win2k8 also shows 6Gb installed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine was running an old BIOS (1.0.3) and the latest was 1.0.18. - and this limited the motherboard to 4Gb of RAM.

Upgrading the BIOS fixed the problem, and all 6Gb is now showing in task manager, and is available to my VMs in Hyper-V.